# C char not saving to file until after app close

Tags: c, file, printf

I'm making a c function and using it with a mac app for testing and learning purposes. When I try to print text to a file using this:

```
FILE *f = fopen("text.txt", "w+");
fflush(f);
if (f==NULL) {
    f = fopen("text.txt", "w+");
    saveToFile(text);
    printf("null\n");
    return 0;
}
else{
    int i = fprintf(f, "%s", text);
    if (i>0) {
        return  1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
fclose(f);
```

it prints it to the file, but only after I quit the app. Anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: 0

can you share the saveToFile() function too please, when I run this code it says missing function and uninitialised text I would like to understand this program. I'm new to C. I really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `return` no matter what before your program can ever reach the `fclose`. So your program is holding off writing to the file until it's closed (because of buffering). When you terminate the program, the files are being closed for you.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam: You should mark this as the answer so it's removed from the "unanswered" list